# How could I select a column based on another column in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, case, case-when

The following script works fine. But I want to write it in one line rather than three lines. 'Size" is passed from my main program and its used here to test. Simply I want to get Price based on size.

Table columns :
LISTING_ID, PRICE_LARGE_PRICE, PRICE_SMALL_PRICE.

```
SET @Size = 'SMALL';

SELECT 
    PRICE_LARGE_PRICE,PRICE_SMALL_PRICE
INTO
    @PRICE_LARGE_PRICE,@PRICE_SMALL_PRICE
FROM
    prices
WHERE
    PRICE_LISTING_ID = 60;

SET @ITEM_PRICE = (CASE @Size WHEN 'REGULAR' THEN @PRICE_LARGE_PRICE 
WHEN 'SMALL' THEN @PRICE_SMALL_PRICE 
ELSE null 
END); 

SELECT @ITEM_PRICE;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following may work.

```
SET @Size = 'SMALL';

SELECT 
    PRICE_LARGE_PRICE,
    PRICE_SMALL_PRICE, 
    CASE WHEN @Size = 'REGULAR' THEN PRICE_LARGE_PRICE
         WHEN @Size = 'SMALL' THEN PRICE_SMALL_PRICE
    END AS ITEM_PRICE 
INTO
    @PRICE_LARGE_PRICE,
    @PRICE_SMALL_PRICE, 
    @ITEM_PRICE 
FROM
    prices
WHERE
    PRICE_LISTING_ID = 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
SELECT 
  IF(@size == 'SMALL', PRICE_SMALL_PRICE, PRICE_LARGE_PRICE) AS ITEM_PRICE 
FROM prices;
```